# Extract YouTube link from Tweet using Python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, youtube, bots

I am trying to phish the YouTube link from a specific tweet and open it in the browser.

I open the URL for the Tweet which is this (https://twitter.com/MrSlagovich/status/1189669505829670912) and then i try to get the YouTube link out of it. Which is this (https://youtu.be/le2v90CQyhs)

I've tried using find element by name find element by tag and I can't seem to fish the url out of the page. Any help would be great. Below is my current code for tying to get it.

`YTLink = bot.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").get_attribute("src")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
url = 'https://twitter.com/MrSlagovich/status/1189669505829670912'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

overlay=driver.find_element_by_id("permalink-overlay-dialog")
YTLink=overlay.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='twitter-timeline-link u-hidden']").get_attribute("title")
```

Comment: That's very close to what i need. It works but i think i missed out a step. The way you have suggested works if i open it when not signed in but when i'm signed in and go through the mentions it opens the tweet like this instead of the way it opened for you when you opened the link.

What you seen: https://i.imgur.com/2CRIwvV.png
What i seen: https://i.imgur.com/l2Shtkb.png

Comment: Reverting the twitter layout back to the original one fixed my issues. Thank you so much man.